# How to save my data when I refresh page?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to save my progress bar with text around it, when I refresh page. I try to save session storage but without result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the sessionStorage API, you can retrieve the value of your key using

```
sessionStorage.getItem('votPoints');
```

This will return a string so you might want to convert it back to JSON if you're going to use it within Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to retrieve your value from session storage like this:

```
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('votPoints');
```

Comment: Yeah, but in my example above, i fill my progress bar, only when someone link is clicked, but not when the page is regresh ..